# Oracle : how to find occurrence of specified value in particular column of a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with one of the columns is `check` and this column has only YES,NO and NA as data

When a query is executed, if the `Check` column has at least one `Yes` value then the `YES` value should be fetched otherwise `NO` value should be fetched and it if no data found for this column then the fetched value should be `NA`

Could someone help me out?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does the table ddl look like? Do you have some sample data (dml) and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I am answering the right question - but I hope this query example would help:

```
Select nvl(MAX(col),'NA')
from (select id, col from table
      where id = 1 
      union all 
      select 1 id, null from dual)
group by id
```

(that would work with YES and NO since 'YES'>'NO' so the priority will be given to 'YES', and then to 'NO' - in the case that there are no results - the nvl will make sure you get NA.
For the case no result exists - the "select id, null from dual will make sure you'll get results).

There are many other ways you can write this query (including analytical functions, and creating an aggregation function, which is what you really want...) - but this is the simplest... (make sure all the col values are only 'YES' and 'NO' by constraint - otherwise the correctness will be harmed..)

Now I am not sure if it answers your question, but if I understand your need correctly, the ideas shown here should be applicable to your requirement.

This should also be pretty efficient, assuming there is an index on the rows you're querying.

Comment: my requirement is that atleast one of the values of that particular field is Yes then Yes has to be fetched Otherwise No will be fetched 
And if that field doesnt have any data then NA will be fetched

try to help me out ........

Comment: Is there anything I missed?

Comment: My requirement is that if the particular column has atleat one "Yes" value then "Yes" value has to be fetched
Otherwise "No" value would be fetched
and incase of no data found for that column then "NA" would be fetched....

could you resolve my pblm mr.evenro

Comment: What I attached here does not does it? which use case does not work?
If you'll be able to upload a script for your table, with some example records, and a query - I'd be able to tailor the full query you should run.

Comment: Could you pls tel me - How does that max(col) function work for string values

Comment: MAX is an aggregation function, for every group in the group by (or for all the data in the table if there's no group by clause) the max function will return the maximum value. for strings- it is by "string" order (since "Y" comes after "N" it will be bigger). if there are no results - Max will not return anything - because of that I added the NULL record, so you'll always get results.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Solution:**

```
 WITH tbl_values as (
      SELECT distinct mt.check_value
        FROM my_table mt
       ORDER BY decode(mt.check_value,'YES',1,'NO',2,3) ASC)

 SELECT tv.check
   FROM tbl_values tv
  WHERE rownum = 1;
```

> **COMMENTS:** The `DECODE` statement is the key enforcement of the rules stated in the OP.